Where can i find all versions of the plugin "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader"?
I am currently using the version 1.0.0 of dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader and I am wondering if exists other ones.
settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
}

